# Add all senders from Entourage to Address Book

Tags: macos, apple-mail, import, contacts, entourage

I am trying to migrate from Entourage to Mail, and the only thing that keeps me using Entourage is  email autocompletion. Entourage connects to the corporate Exchange address book, while Mail can't.

Do you know of a way to import all Entourage senders / contacts into Address Book?

I've tried the following:

1. find an Applescript sample that reads Exchange address books and import all contacts into Mac's contacts. Could not even find an example.
2. add all senders in my inbox to Entourage's address book (by selecting all messages and clicking add sender to address book) - this would in theory work, but on every duplicate it pops up a dialogue box. I tried writing an Applescript that would close all these dialogues, but it turned out to be more difficult than I thought it would be
3. write Applescript that will iterate Entourage emails and add senders to address book (way too much work).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I mostly solved this problem by doing the second solution in Mail instead of Entourage: it just silently adds all senders to contacts without popping up the idiotic popup message